# Proof that the K coloring problem is weakly or strong NP-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete, colorings, pseudo-polynomial

As far as I know, the K coloring problem is NP-complete. However, I'm a bit confused about how to determine whether a problem is weakly or strongly NP-complete.

- If an NP-complete problem is decidable by a pseudo-polynomial time algorithm, it is called weakly NP-complete.
- If an NP-complete problem's unary version is NP-complete, then it is called strongly NP-complete.

**Is there a straightforward proof that the K coloring problem is weakly or strong NP-complete?**

Answer (score 1):

There are no obvious integers involved in an instance of the $K$-coloring problem (where $K$ is part of the problem and not of the input).

The length of the encoding of an instance of $K$-coloring is the length of the encoding of the graph. The [standard reduction from 3-SAT](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/%7Eanuprao/pubs/431/lecture7.pdf) shows that the problem is (strongly) NP-complete.

Even if $K$ were part of the input, this would have no effect on the asymptotic size of the encoding of the input (since only $K \le n$ makes sense, where $n$ is the number of nodes of the graph).

Comment: I want to prove that the 4-Coloring Problem is strongly NP-complete. How can I create an unary version for the 4-Coloring Problem?

Comment: "Unary version: when numbers are represented in unary on the input, for example, 3 is represented as 111, 4 is represented as 1111, etc."

Comment: What numbers are you referring to?

Comment: For example: Assign to each vertex a sequence of ones indicating the corresponding color.For example, if the first vertex is assigned the first color, let it be "1". If the second vertex is assigned the third color, let it be "111". Therefore, each vertex is represented by a sequence of ones, and this sequence is provided in unary encoding.
For instance, if the coloring of vertices looks like this: red = 1, blue = 11, green = 111, yellow = 1111 .
Then: Vertex 1: Blue -> 11, Vertex 2: Red -> 1, Vertex 3: Green -> 111, Vertex 4: Yellow -> 1111

Comment: The color of the vertices is not part of the input though.

Comment: @wellknow 4-coloring has no numerical parameters in the input, which implies strong NP-completeness.

Comment: @rus9384
so it means that 4-coloring problem cannot be a strongly NP-complete, but a weakly NP-complete.How can i generate a pseudo-polynomial time algorithm for this problem to prove that 4-coloring problem is weakly NP-complete?

Comment: @wellknow It is strongly NP-complete, because you don't need any parameter. Just as how 3-SAT is strongly NP-complete, because 3 is not a parameter.

Comment: @rus9384. You can't (unless $P=NP$). If $P \neq NP$ there does not exist any pseudo-polynomial time algorithm for this problem.

Comment: I meant that an absence of numerical parameters in an NP-complete problem implies strong NP-completeness.

Comment: so, to prove that this problem is strongly NP-complete, is it sufficient to reduce a Np-complete problem to this problem? (if P!=NP)

Comment: @wellknow it is sufficient to reduce a strongly NP-complete problem to this problem (regardless of the $P$ vs $NP$ matter). As I said in the answer, the standard reduction from 3-SAT suffices to 3-COLORING suffices (to get a reduction to $4$-coloring simply add a universal vertex).

Comment: I see :O it wasn't entirely clear to me yet, but now I get it. Thanks. :)